# how to use on update in postgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert this following SQL create query to postgreSQL and got stuck.. please help..

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
      testname varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
      testStartTime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```

Am just a beginner in postgreSql and can't make out how the "on update" thing can be converted into postgreSql. Is it possible using trigger? If yes please explain..
        Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `ON UPDATE` clause is shorthand for a before trigger that keeps the row's value to whatever is specified. So, yes, you can use a before trigger to achieve the same.

In fact, I vaguely recollect a mention of a built-in trigger somewhere in the Postgres manual for this specific use-case — but I can't seem to recollect where. At any rate, the gist of it is something like:

```
create function foo() returns trigger as $$
begin
  new.testStartTime := now();
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger before update on bar
for each row execute procedure foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example of an update trigger](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/) in Postgres.